# Simulink - Code to 'Comment through' blocks

Tags: matlab, simulink

I've built a Simulink model and I would like to 'Comment Through' some blocks via a MATLAB script. I am using MATLAB 2013b.

I know that the command `set_param('BlockAddress','Commented','on')` comments out the block from the simulation, but that's not the same thing.

Instead of the string 'Commented' in the `set_param` code, I was hoping to find a block property that defines the 'Comment Through' state, but I could not find it in MATLAB's [Common Block Properties](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/simulink/slref/common-block-parameters.html?searchHighlight=set_param%20blocks%20commented) page.

Does anyone know if such property is defined, or, if not, a different work-around to comment through blocks by using a script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite MATLAB did not mention 'through' among the possible values for the 'Commented' property, this is the code to comment out blocks using `set_param`:

`set_param('BlockAddress','Commented','through')`

Comment: Are you sure this code works? It didn't work in Matlab 2012b

Comment: I am sure it works in Matlab 2013b.. As it wasn't documented probably they introduced it in 2013a or b. Now it's already 2015b and it's properly documented online